# Activity onStop() method called twice

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, activity-lifecycle

Launching another activity from `PendingIntent` on lock screen causes current activitie's (which is `onStop()` state) `onStop()` to be called twice. Below is test code. Is it intended behavior of android or bug?

```
  import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;



    public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        Log.w("app_test", "onCreate()");
        showNotification();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.w("app_test", "onResume()");
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.w("app_test", "onStop()");
        super.onStop();
    }
    public void showNotification() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNEL_ID")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Content text")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(102, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Here is the log results

```
W/app_test: onCreate()
W/app_test: onResume()
W/app_test: onStop()
W/app_test: onStop()
```

Comment: Is the `TestActivity` is same Activity which shown above?

Comment: @ADM No. Different.

Comment: Can you add full code with class name

Comment: @Milap edited my question.

Comment: There is nothing tricky in this code everything is perfect can you please add code from where you started Activity2.

Comment: @Milap `Activity1` -> `Activity2`. `launching mode`s are `standard` for activities.

Comment: @Bek put Activity1 code and androidmanifest.

Comment: Is this on emulator or on a device? Have you tried other devices?

Comment: @David on real device. I reasked my question in a detailed way. Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50167202/activity-onresume-is-not-called