# Current activities onResume() is not called when another Activity is launched from lock screen via notification

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-pendingintent

I have two activities `Activity2` and `TestActivity`. `Activity2` shows notification when launched. `TestActivity` is launched when notification is clicked. Below is the code of `Activity2.java`.

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.droidapp.apptest.R;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);
        Log.w("app_test", "onCreate()");
        showNotification();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        Log.w("app_test", "onStart()");
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        Log.w("app_test", "onRestart()");
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.w("app_test", "onResume()");
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.w("app_test", "onPause()");
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.w("app_test", "onStop()");
        super.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.w("app_test", "onDestroy()");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    public void showNotification() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNEL_ID")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Content text")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(102, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Below all lifecycle methods belongs to `Activity2`.

When Activity2 first time launched. Here `onCreate()` notification is shown.

```
W/app_test: onCreate()
W/app_test: onStart()
W/app_test: onResume()
```

After pressing home button

```
W/app_test: onPause()
W/app_test: onStop()
```

After clicking notification `TestActivity` is launched. `Activity2` lifecycle methods aren't called. Everything is working as expected.

If instead of pressing home button, I press power button

```
W/app_test: onPause()
W/app_test: onStop()
```

Then click notification from lock screen `Activity2` lifecycle methods are called.

```
W/app_test: onRestart()
W/app_test: onStart()
W/app_test: onStop()
```

And then `TestActivity` is launched. Here strange thing is `Activity2` `onResume()` isn't called.

But if I don't click notification, and just unlock screen by swiping `onResume()` is called.

```
W/app_test: onRestart()
W/app_test: onStart()
W/app_test: onResume()
```

In my real application I register `BroadcastReceiver` on activities `onResume()` state and unregister it `onPause()`. Unregistering `BroadcastReceiver` which wasn't registered causes `IllegalStateException`. Now I'm avoiding this exception by putting `boolean` variable.

**Question. Is it expected behaviour or bug in android framework?**

**Edit**. Even more strange thing.
If I first press home button, then power button and then click notification from lock screen.

```
W/app_test: onRestart()
W/app_test: onStart()
W/app_test: onResume()
W/app_test: onPause()
W/app_test: onStop()
```

And then `TestActivity` is launched.

activity properties in manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.Activity2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
<activity android:name=".activities.TestActivity"/>
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear. Does TestActivity also shows notification that opens Activity2?

Comment: @Rushi No. It's an empty activity

Comment: its not a full source code of `Activity2`, is it?

Comment: @pskink It's full source code.

Comment: log your `TestActivty` 's states also at the time of pressing power-button and clicking on notification then.

Comment: @pskink It's because of `PendingIntent`.

Comment: @InsaneCat please remove your flag. My question is different. It's not duplicate.

Comment: @Bek Ok why not first wrote full description.

Comment: Please share activity entry in AndroidManifest file for both the activities.

Comment: @maveroid added.

Comment: last part is strange after editing, rest is as per expected behavior. Can you confirm the behavior by taking logs again?

Comment: @maveroid I tested lots of time. After pressing home button everything works as expected. But without pressing home, if I press power button then click notification from locked screen `onResume()` is not called.

Comment: Yes, that is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This is as per expected behavior since when you click the notification from lock screen `Activity2` is not visible and goes to background behind `TestActivity` screen and hence its `onResume()` won't be called. However, when you don't click the notification and just unlock your phone, `Activity2` gets visible and its `onResume()` will be called. Hope it helps.

Comment: I accidentally downvote your answer while scrolling. Edit your answer so that I can upvote.

Comment: @Bek, Edited now.